# Shear stress for non-linear vs linear velocity profiles

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, stress-strain, viscosity

In this question, I would like to consider 3 scenarios: 1) Fluid of uniform viscosity between 2 parallel flat plates with linear velocity profile, 2) 2 different fluids with different viscosities between 2 parallel flat plates, with linear velocity profiles within each layer of fluid, and 3) fluid of uniform viscosity between 2 parallel flat plates with non-linear velocity profile. The diagram below more clearly illustrates scenario 2:

[image]

It turns out that for scenarios 1 and 2, the shear stress experienced through the fluid(s) is constant. However, for scenario 3, shear stress turns out to be non-constant throughout the fluid. I understand that the equation $\tau = \mu \frac{dv}{dh}$, where $\tau$ is the shear stress, $\mu$ is the viscosity, $v$ is fluid velocity and $h$ is vertical distance from one of the plates, governs all three scenarios. So, in scenario 3, because $\frac{dv}{dh}$ is not constant and $\mu$ is constant, then $\tau$ varies with $\frac{dv}{dh}$. However, why does shear stress remain constant across both fluids of different viscosity in scenario 2? What governs how much shear stress is experienced by a fluid in such scenarios?

Comment: The force balance  gives a constant shear stress which then gives a constant velocity gradient in scenario 2 for each fluid.

Comment: @ChetMiller Hmmm but why must the forces exerted by the plates on the fluid on the top and the bottom be equal and opposite? And why does this not hold in scenario 3?

Comment: The forces on the plates have to be equal because the fluid is not accelerating; the system is at steady state.

Comment: @ChetMiller How does this contrast with Scenario 3? I appreciate your replies but I'm still not very clear about this. I'm a beginner in this topic

Comment: In scenario 3, there’s an axial pressure gradient.